# Match text and img in Datatables PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, datatables

So, I'm generating some dummy data with [FakerPHP](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)

Either by generating data or manually putting it into my Datatables
Based on the BRAND of the car, id like to automatically display the right IMG

For example I generate 500 new rows of BRAND "AUDI"
and I want to auto display "AUDI.jpg"
In every column that BRAND is AUDI, display the logo picture as well.

What would be the optimal way to do this?
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QSus.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can name logo picture same as brand name so that in picture column you can display logo base on brand name like the recontructed table below:

```
<table border="1">

                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th >BRAND</th>
                        <th >Model</th>
                        <th >Sub model</th>
                        <th >year</th>
                        <th >price</th>
                        <th >Photo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
    
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['brand']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['model']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['submodel']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                        <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['brand']; ?>.jpg" alt="" ></td>
                    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: You are correct! Thx